# Kentico Kontent and Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, kentico-kontent, kontent-ai

I'm searching for a simple example on how to create a component in Vue 3 using data out of Kontent. More specifically, I'm trying to list items of a certain content type. I tried to refactor the Vue sample app that Kentico provided, but I'm quite new to programming and Vue and I can't seem to figure it out...

The following code gives an error saying `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`:

```html
<template v-for="(item, index) in eventsData" :key="index">
  <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import { Client } from "../Client"; //seperated this, the connection works

export default {
  name: 'Test',
  setup() {
    const data = Client
    .items()
    .type("event")
    .toObservable()
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response) //this works, data is displayed in the console
      return response.items;
    });

    return {data};
  },
  computed: { 
    eventsData: function() {
      return this.data.map(event => ({
        name: event.name
      }));
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Edit2: Based on eyeslandic's hint I tried to improve my code, but I'm stuck again. The variables inside `setup()` are not accessable outside of it, so how do I get the outcome to `data()`?

This is what I have now:

```html
<template>
  <div class="test-div">
    <template v-for="(item, index) in eventsData" :key="index">
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Client } from "../Client";

export default {
  name: 'Test',
  setup() {
    let events = [];

    const kontent = Client
    .items()
    .type("event")
    .toObservable()
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);//this works
      events = response.items;
      console.log("events inside kontent variable: " + events)//[object object][object object]
    });

    console.log("events outside kontent variable: " + events);//nothing
    console.log("kontent inside setup: " + kontent)//[object object]

    return {
      events,
      kontent
    };
  },  
  data() {
    return {
      eventList: events, //error: undefined,
      eventList2: kontent //error: undefined
    }
  },
  computed: {
    eventsData: function() {
      return this.eventList.map(event => ({
        name: event.name.value
      }));
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`events` needs to be a [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref) or [`reactive`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive) for it to be reactive. Also, you could use the Composition API's [`computed`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#computed) to create a computed property from `setup()`:

```html
<template>
  <p v-for="(name, index) in eventList" :key="index">
    {{ name }}
  </p>
</template>

<script>
import { computed, reactive } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const events = ref([])
  
    Client.items()
      .type('event')
      .toObservable()
      .subscribe(response => events.value = response.items)

    return {
      eventList: computed(() => events.value.map(event => ({ name: event.name.value }))
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

There's no need to return `events` or `kontent` from `setup()`, since they're not used anywhere in the template. I see your attempt at referencing `kontent` in `data()`, but `eventList` and `eventList2` are also unused. The template you've shown could rely exclusively on `setup()` with the solution shown above.